# How to display data in my navbar in each page?

Tags: php, symfony

in Symfony 5, i want to display entities `Categories` in my navbar for each page of my website. Actually i return the same data in each function in my controller like

```
return $this->render('post/index.html.twig', ['Categories' => $Categories]);
```

I want to know if there is a better way to return always my categories instead of always retrieve data in each function and return the same data ?

Comment: If your categories aren't changing then you could look into Twig global variables added to the twig.yaml file and add all your categories there. But what you're already doing is fine, especially in production if you use caching.

Comment: Sadly, I can add some new categories, that's why ! Thank you for your help !

Comment: You can use your `CategoryRepository` as a [twig global](https://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/global_variables.html#referencing-services).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your navbar is the same on all pages, instead of including the navbar template like `{% include 'base/navbar.html.twig' %}`, you can include a Controller that will pull the Categories from the database and render the template. It's explained here : https://symfony.com/doc/current/templates.html#embedding-controllers.

In your template :

```
{{ render(controller('App\\Controller\\BaseController::navbar')) }}
```

In BaseController

```
public function navbar(CategoriesRepository $categoriesRepository) {
    return $this->render('base/navbar.html.twig', [
        'categories' => $categoriesRepository->findAll(),
    ]);
}
```

You don't need to add annotations, because there's no route. It's simply a function that returns html.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use global variables. For example in `config/packages/twig.yaml`:

```yaml
twig:
    globals:
        varKey: varValue
```

or to create own [Twig Extension](https://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/twig_extension.html)